# PHP Datetime: How to get the differnce between DateTime Object and Current Time

Tags: php, datetime

I have a DateTime Object and I want to get the differnce between this and the current date. But I always get ZERO as my differnce, but that cannot be. Can't find the answer. Could anyone help me? THANK YOU!

```
private function checkAge($date) {
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $diffDate = ($currentDate-$result);
    echo $diffDate;
    if ($diffDate>=43200) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You mixed up PHP's object-oriented & procedural functions. `date()` will return `string`, instead of `DateTime` object. RTFM

Comment: what is the $date var? a datetime PHP object?

Comment: I get the DateTime Object from my Doctrine Database. And I just want to compare the saved Date form my DB with the current date.

Comment: $date is a \DateTime Object

Comment: What is the point of this method? What do you need to do? Return `true` if datetimes are more than 12hour different?

Comment: Thanks, the answer from JIM was good for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$currentDate` and `$result` are both strings. Subtracting them is not going to give the difference between the two dates.

You can either use the [DateTime diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method or, if you just need the seconds you can compare timestamps:

```
private function checkAge($date) {
    $currentDate = date('U');
    $result = $date->format('U');
    $diffDate = ($currentDate-$result);
    echo $diffDate;
    if ($diffDate>=43200) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the the diff function to compare dates ?

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```